# why is google places api giving peer certificate error

Tags: java, android, http, connection, peer

Getting a peer certificate error with google places api with the following http request code: -> ( I don't think I need to add SSLSocketFactory etc when using google places api http request) Can anyone tell me how to fix this please?

```
   public JSONObject showPorts() 
         throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

            // StringBuilder portURL = new StringBuilder(pURL);        
            // HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
     StringBuilder portURL = new StringBuilder(pURL);        
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(portURL.toString());
             Log.d(TAG,pURL);                        

             HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
             int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

             if(status == 200){
                 Log.d(TAG,"200");                       

             HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
             String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
```